# jGiven Output Directory

Tags: java, maven, appium, jgiven

Is there a way to change the output directory for the generated reports to an custom directory - in particular for the .json-Report files?

Documentation says (http://jgiven.org/userguide/ - 4.2):

> [...] JGiven tries to autodetect when it is executed by the Maven surefire plugin [I'm using it] and in that case generates the reports into target/jgiven-reports/json. [...]

I'm using jGiven with Maven (for Appium Tests).

Configuration (pom.xml - dependencies):

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.tngtech.jgiven</groupId>
        <artifactId>jgiven-testng</artifactId>
        <version>0.15.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Configuration (pom.xml - build/plugins):

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>com.tngtech.jgiven</groupId>
        <artifactId>jgiven-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.15.1</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <goals>
                    <goal>report</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
</plugin>
```

Since the directory is defined by jGiven it does not help to change the build-directory. It would still use the `target/jgiven-reports/json` directory.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If somebody else is curious:

I found: `String reportDirName = System.getProperty( JGIVEN_REPORT_DIR );` in https://github.com/TNG/JGiven/blob/fae0f3c8db0b00e7fa233cbd8f86306379def4b2/jgiven-core/src/main/java/com/tngtech/jgiven/impl/Config.java#L31 (current master).

Important part of it:

```
private static final String TRUE = "true";
private static final String FALSE = "false";
private static final String AUTO = "auto";
private static final String JGIVEN_REPORT_ENABLED = "jgiven.report.enabled";
public static final String JGIVEN_REPORT_DIR = "jgiven.report.dir";
private static final String JGIVEN_REPORT_TEXT = "jgiven.report.text";
private static final String JGIVEN_REPORT_TEXT_COLOR = "jgiven.report.text.color";
private static final String JGIVEN_FILTER_STACK_TRACE = "jgiven.report.filterStackTrace";
```

So you can either set your system properties via the maven-surefire-plugin in the pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <configuration>
                <systemPropertyVariables>
                    <jgiven.report.dir>/my/custom/dir</jgiven.report.dir>
                </systemPropertyVariables>
            </configuration>
</plugin>
```

or just use Java's `System.setProperty("jgiven.report.dir", "/my/custom/dir")`

Comment: This is now [officially documented](http://jgiven.org/userguide/#_change_report_directory).